# C put contents of file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file, tokenize, file-read

I'm trying to get tokens from a file and put it into an array. However, it keeps failing. The tokens I want are only alphanumeric and numeric. Everything else is a delimiter.

Code:

```
void readFile(WORDS list, char *filepath)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, ch; 
    char *token, *temp;
    FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "r");

    if(file)
    {
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        long f_size = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        token = malloc(f_size);
        temp = malloc(f_size);

        while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            temp[i++] = (char) ch;

            if(regeval(temp, "^[0-9][0-9]*$"))
                token[j++] = (char) ch;
            else if(regeval(temp, "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
                token[j++] = (char) ch;
            else
            {
                token[j] = '\0';

                memset(token, 0, sizeof(f_size));
                memset(temp, 0, sizeof(f_size));
                i = j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int regeval(char *str, char *exp)
{
    // Make regex object
    regex_t regex;

    // Compile and execute expression
    int reg = regcomp(&regex, exp, REG_EXTENDED);
    reg = regexec(&regex, str, 0, NULL, 0);

    // Expression matches token
    if(!reg)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

If I have a file named test.txt with the content: `Abacus` in it, it will only print out `Abac`. What am I doing wrong? I thought it was a nullbyte issue so I added that line in, but nothing changed.

**UPDATE**: Updated code. However, it prints out Segmentation fault.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Since `EOF` is an `int` and not a `char`, your loop will either fail to properly detect end-of-file, or will misinterpret data as an end-of-file condition, possibly both.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I updated the code. However, it keeps saying Segmentation fault. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you tried running it with Valgrind (Linux) or Dr. Memory (Windows)? That should be your first resource when debugging segmentation faults.

Comment: You're calling `fclose()` even if `file` is `NULL`.